# jQuery get all table rows until class

Tags: jquery, loops, html-table

I am having a table rows from db via ajax and I have this sample:

```
<tr class="header packagesTR expand">
   <td>                             
      Boxing Amateur
   </td>
   <td>
      0                                                     
   </td>                                                        
   <td width="20%"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning pull-left showInclude"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>                             
       Sparring Fee 
   </td>
   <td>
      0                                                     
   </td>                                                        

</tr>
<tr>
   <td>     
      Water
   </td>
   <td>
        0                                                       
   </td>                                                        
</tr>
<tr class="header packagesTR expand">
   <td>     
      <input type="hidden" name="category" value="packages">
    <input type="hidden" name="PK" value="2">                           
       Muay Thai Amateur
   </td>
   <td>
    0                                                       
   </td>                                                        
 </tr>
```

When I clicked on the ".showInclude" button, I want to get the current table row and the next table rows until the next class name "header".

I am able to get the current table, by:

```
 $(this).closest('tr.header').html();
```

How  can I iterate through each table row until the next class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i clicked on the ".showInclude" button, i want to get the current table row and the next table rows until the next class name "header".

You can use `.nextUntil()` along with `.add()` to add current row header in collection:

```
var closesrthr= $(this).closest('tr.header');
closesrthr.nextUntil('.header').add(closesrthr).nextUntil('.header').html();
```

> How i can iterate through each table row until the next class?

You have the object of rows current row `.header` and rows until next first sibling `.header`. you can iterate over them using each:

```
var closesrthr= $(this).closest('tr.header');
closesrthr.nextUntil('.header').add(closesrthr).each(function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L3jdme6e/)**

Comment: I already used that, but only the next trow is being get. I need the current, and next rows.

Comment: Oh ! Working now. Thank you :)

Comment: i use the inside "each function" with 

form.push($(this).html())

does $(form).seralizeArray(); work on this?

Comment: @user3651476: yes it will.

Comment: how can i check ? cause i want to see if im passing the correct data. I have enclosed it in <form> method. cause when i alert, its empty.

Comment: @user3651476: would be great if you can post the new question with relevant code :). it is hard to interpret things through comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89894/discussion-between-user3651476-and-milind-anantwar).